# JSQmessagesviewcontroller sent and receive messages in IOS swift

Tags: swift

i'm able to display sent message on collection view , how to display received messages from parse database using JSQmessagesviewcontroller in ios using swift? is there any tutorials ?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it

Comment: i'm creating chat app, i managed to display sent message using JSQMessage  but not saving it to the database. now i want to know how to display received message from parse database. I dont know how to diferentiate sent  and received messages using JSQMessage

Comment: Remove the thing about Tutorials. Add this comment to your Question. Also add relevant code snippets to help people understand your parse structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.udemy.com/swift-ios-chat-app-from-scratch-community-course/
this course helped me with my app, he use jsqmessages and parse